# Unique constraint where column name does not match

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, unique-constraint

I have a table that lists all different makes/models of cars:

```
 Make, Model, Year
```

Each row is unique, like "Chevrolet Camaro 1969"

I then have a table that lists "model groups", cars that are often grouped together like the 1967-1969 Camaros.  So:

```
Make, Model, StartYear, EndYear, GroupName
```

I added a Unique contraint for "Make-Model-StartYear" and "Make-Model-EndYear".

I wanted to add a foreign key mapping the start year back to the Models table, basically to enforce this:

```
Chevrolet, Camaro, 1967, 1969, FirstGenerationCamaro
-> Chevrolet, Camaro, 1967 should exist in the Model table
-> Chevrolet, Camaro, 1969 should exist in the Model table
```

When I try to do this (in the SQL Management Studio) I create a foreign key mapping:

```
Group.Make -> Model.Make, Group.Model -> Model.Model, Group.StartYear -> Model.StartYear
Group.Make -> Model.Make, Group.Model -> Model.Model, Group.EndYear   -> Model.EndYear
```

In English, the group row that says "1967-1969 Chevrolet Camaro" should enforce that there is a model entry for both "1967 Chevrolet Camaro" and "1969 Chevrolet Camaro".

The problem I am having is the error "Columns do not match a primary key or existing UNIQUE constraint".  But I do indeed have unqiue constraints for for "Make-Model-StartYear" and "Make-Model-EndYear".

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way, but how do I ensure that there is in fact a Model entry for both the start year and end year of the group?

Thanks,
Dave

PS: SQL2008 R2

Comment: Shouldn't that be Model.Year on the right side?

Comment: I guess Griffin is asking about the `Model.StartYear` and `Model.EndYear` entries in your foreign key mappings, i.e. whether *they* should not both be `Model.Year` (in case you get puzzled by the question).

Comment: Note you lack a sequenced key e.g. `( Chevrolet, Camaro, 1968, 1970,  OopsOverlappingCamaro)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where your error comes from but this seams to work the way you want.

```
create table Model
(
  Make varchar(25) not null,
  Model varchar(25) not null,
  Year int not null, 

  primary key (Make, Model, Year)
)

create table ModelGroup
(
  Make varchar(25) not null,
  Model varchar(25) not null,
  StartYear int not null,
  EndYear int not null,
  GroupName varchar(30) not null,

  primary key (Make, Model, StartYear),
  unique (Make, Model, EndYear),
  foreign key (Make, Model, StartYear) references Model(Make, Model, Year),
  foreign key (Make, Model, EndYear) references Model(Make, Model, Year)
)
```

BTW, The primary key and unique constraint in `ModelGroup` is not necessary for the foreign key to work. It **is** however necessary to have a primary key (or unique constraint) on `Make, Model, Year` in `Model`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:  the primary key in the models table had the columns in the order:

```
Year, Make, Model
```

I needed to reference them by

```
Make, Model, Year
```

I did not know that order within the key was relevant for foreign keys;